# Zoom-In and Zoom-Out can not resize?

Tags: printing, mfc, preview

I'm using MFC Print preview dialog.  Before I used BMP image to represent those zoom buttons and they worked fine, but now I want to use the text labeling instead. But no matter what value I use, the size remains the same when I run the program.  Here below what I have:

```
IDD_FILE_KHANH_PRINT_PREVIEW DIALOG  0, 0, 219, 19
STYLE DS_SETFONT | WS_CHILD

FONT 8, "MS Sans Serif"
BEGIN

PUSHBUTTON "&Print",AFX_ID_PREVIEW_PRINT,2,3,36,12
PUSHBUTTON "Zoom &In",AFX_ID_PREVIEW_ZOOMIN,40,3,46,50
PUSHBUTTON "Zoom &Out",AFX_ID_PREVIEW_ZOOMOUT,70,3,46,12
PUSHBUTTON "Pre&v Page",AFX_ID_PREVIEW_PREV,100,3,46,12
PUSHBUTTON "&Next Page",AFX_ID_PREVIEW_NEXT,150,3,46,12
CONTROL "Landscape",IDC_LANDSCAPE,"Button",BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | WS_TABSTOP,230,3,67,13,WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE
PUSHBUTTON "&Close",AFX_ID_PREVIEW_CLOSE,300,3,35,13
END
```

SO I change the values for two buttons, and one is working while zoom-in does not work, for example:

```
PUSHBUTTON        "&Print",AFX_ID_PREVIEW_PRINT,2,3,136,12
```

this one works because i can see the Print button has wider length.  So I change the value from 36 to 136.

```
PUSHBUTTON        "Zoom &In",AFX_ID_PREVIEW_ZOOMIN,40,3,146,50
```

But this one does not work because the ZoomIn remains the same size and here I change 46 to 146.

I believe this is only the place that I assign the values for the buttons.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The height of your "Zoom &In" button is 50 but the dialog height itself is only 19. You should change the the height of the button so it is 12 just like the others.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out and now I just change the height from 50 to 13 so will be like this: 40,3,146,13.  But the length of the zoomIn does not change though.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I made a mistake.  Before I used bitmap image to represent those buttons and when I decide to use text labeling and forgot this function below that loads the bitmap of the zooming buttons.  So after commenting out the m_zoomIn and m_zoomOut statements, they work now.

```
int CKhanhPrintPreview::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    if (CPreviewView::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
    return -1;

    m_pToolBar->EnableToolTips( TRUE );

    m_zoomIn.AutoLoad(AFX_ID_PREVIEW_ZOOMIN, m_pToolBar, IDB_PREV_ZOOMIN );
    m_zoomOut.AutoLoad(AFX_ID_PREVIEW_ZOOMOUT, m_pToolBar, IDB_PREV_ZOOMOUT );

    return 0;
}
```

thanks.